# How can I check STRING SIMILARITY in C++?

Tags: c++, string, string-matching

Say I have 2 strings:

string1 = "abcdef"

string2 = "12abcdef21"

I am looking for a piece of code that analyses these 2 strings and gives a percentage on how similar they are (using the number of characters). The similar part is "abcdef", thus a continuous part of string that matches and not single characters.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

What I actually want to do is to find duplicate files.
I have two files that have the same size and I want to check if they also have similar names.
Any ideas how that can be done ?

Comment: There has to be algorithms available online for this. For example, [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures) looks pretty relevant.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find [That's one of my always accessible browser tabs](http://en.cppreference.com). Looking up there is usually faster than writing a (valid) question on SO.

Comment: @qla_alp Do you mean the maximum common substring of the two strings saying about similarity?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I will check out the links and see If I find something that I can use.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, finding the maximun common substring, and then dividing its size with the size of the string I want to check.

Comment: I had to do this once for a class project in which the input strings could be millions of characters long. We ended up implementing a Greedy Algorithm that gives a `Longest Common Substring` result. Turns out to be quite efficient and if I recall correctly executed in O(n) time with improvement with O(2n) space requirement. Here is the related [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). Once you ran through the algorithm the resulting LCS length was located in the bottom right index of the 2D matrix and you could even reproduce and print the actual string if needbe.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different approaches you can take with this, and a number of established algorithms.

To compare words more by how they sound than how they are spelled, you could try a variation on the Soundex algoright ([Phonetic String Comparison with Soundex](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/phonetic-string-comparison-with-soundex)).

To score words based on how similar the characters are, you might look at ([Approximate String Comparisons Using Levenshtein Distance](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/approximate-string-comparisons-using-levenshtein-distance)).

Note: Both articles include C# code, but the approach wold be the same in C++.